Elasticsearch: how to drop the properties from being stored if the value is null
We have an index template with can up to 150 properties. Some properties will have value as null depend on the field called "RecordType".
How Elasticsearch can drop the properties having null to optimise the index size? Instead of being updated with null values.
For example, Consider there is a doc with 5 properties. Both recordType (prepaid & postpaid) using the same index template.
{
  "firstName" : "mary", 
  "lastName" : "nelson", 
  "phone" : "1234567",
  "expiryDate" : "31/12/2025",
  "company" : null,   //null for Prepaid
  "billCycle": null   //null for Prepaid
  "recordTpe" : "Prepaid"
}

{
  "firstName" : "mary", 
  "lastName" : "nelson", 
  "phone" : "1234567",
  "expiryDate": null,   // null for Postpaid 
  "company" : "companyA",
  "billCycle": "monthly"
  "recordTpe" : "Postpaid"
}

Will it make a difference, if we choose to drop the properties from being stored if the value is null
{
  "firstName" : "mary", 
  "lastName" : "nelson", 
  "phone" : "1234567",
  "expiryDate" : "31/12/2025",
  "recordTpe" : "Prepaid"
}

{
  "firstName" : "mary", 
  "lastName" : "nelson", 
  "phone" : "1234567",
  "company" : "companyA",
  "billCycle": "monthly"
  "recordTpe" : "Postpaid"
}

Properties with null value can be drop in Elasticsearch (which in my example depend on the recordType"? So that:

the null value will not be indexed
the null value will not be stored to reduce index size

If yes, how I can achieve that? Thanks in advance.

You don't need to worry about the null value because:

A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to
null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as
though that field has no values.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html

If you want to remove the field if the value is null you can check this stackoverflow answer.
